# Is TypeScript mistyping this reduce expression? Why?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=7&pln=4&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG9SQFxQEQENcBfKAH3Uwh1wCNiyLwq8BjYgWAChKoAlCAM4BXADbAU6fAH4cGJtUJEANFBozG2VsRUt1czbjZEuXFgHsAdgPEAnQaPGouUF1ADa+5gW0avdZb7URgC6zq4AdHYAJkIsEAAU8fgsLDj8wmIqZjQAVjhwiACUKAB86GGurgIA7gCWwCwAFlDx2TnhlMVoFZW9LPgC0N5YPb1jUHbAQjYW6OHzySwq+DhtxpzjfQNDdCMbm+OT07No8+GLKjSruesHrv2DWnt3Y0czcwspOtc5ty9REAAZvgHM8XpVgI0bGZqlALBBYQBRGzQmzxXC1CwAN3wIlqUVwhVGrj+LgCaCIhSAA):

```js
type Item = {type: "a"} | {type: "b"} | {type: "c"}
type Result = {a?: {type: "a"}, b?: {type: "c"}, c?: {type: "c"}

const result = 
    [{type: "a"}, {type: "b"}, {type: "c"}]
    .reduce((acc: Result, obj: Item) => {
        switch (obj.type) {
            case "a":
                return {...acc, a: obj}
            case "b":
                return {...acc, b: obj}
            case "c":
                return {...acc, c: obj}
            default:
                throw new Error("invalid")
        }
    }, {})
```

I believe that `result` should be of type `Result` but I think TypeScript is instead inferring the reduce expression's type as the same type as each element in the array (e.g. type `Item`).

Please see the error in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=7&pln=4&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG9SQFxQEQENcBfKAH3Uwh1wCNiyLwq8BjYgWAChKoAlCAM4BXADbAU6fAH4cGJtUJEANFBozG2VsRUt1czbjZEuXFgHsAdgPEAnQaPGouUF1ADa+5gW0avdZb7URgC6zq4AdHYAJkIsEAAU8fgsLDj8wmIqZjQAVjhwiACUKAB86GGurgIA7gCWwCwAFlDx2TnhlMVoFZW9LPgC0N5YPb1jUHbAQjYW6OHzySwq+DhtxpzjfQNDdCMbm+OT07No8+GLKjSruesHrv2DWnt3Y0czcwspOtc5ty9REAAZvgHM8XpVgI0bGZqlALBBYQBRGzQmzxXC1CwAN3wIlqUVwhVGrj+LgCaCIhSAA).

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: { type: string; }, currentValue: { type: string; }, currentIndex: number, array: { type: string; }[]) => { type: string; }, initialValue: { type: string; }): { type: string; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: Result, obj: Item) => { a: { type: "a"; }; b?: { type: "c"; } | undefined; c?: { type: "c"; } | undefined; } | { b: { type: "b"; }; a?: { type: "a"; } | undefined; c?: { type: "c"; } | undefined; } | { c: { type: "c"; }; a?: { ...; } | undefined; b?: { ...; } | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: { type: string; }, currentValue: { type: string; }, currentIndex: number, array: { type: string; }[]) => { type: string; }'.
      Types of parameters 'acc' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.
        Type '{ type: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'Result'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(callbackfn: (previousValue: Result, currentValue: { type: string; }, currentIndex: number, array: { type: string; }[]) => Result, initialValue: Result): Result', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(acc: Result, obj: Item) => { a: { type: "a"; }; b?: { type: "c"; } | undefined; c?: { type: "c"; } | undefined; } | { b: { type: "b"; }; a?: { type: "a"; } | undefined; c?: { type: "c"; } | undefined; } | { c: { type: "c"; }; a?: { ...; } | undefined; b?: { ...; } | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: Result, currentValue: { type: string; }, currentIndex: number, array: { type: string; }[]) => Result'.
      Types of parameters 'obj' and 'currentValue' are incompatible.
        Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Item'.
          Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "c"; }'.
            Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
Property or signature expected.
```

What's actually going on here and how could this type error be resolved idiomatically?

Comment: Two minor things: `[{type: "a"}, {type: "b"}, {type: "c"}]` needs a type, otherwise it's inferred as containing `{type: string}` not `Item`. You can do `const arr: Item[] = [{type: "a"}, {type: "b"}, {type: "c"}];`. Second, the initial value for `.reduce()` should be `{} as Result` otherwise `{}` is not inferred to be `Result`. With these two the code is correct, however the bigger problem is that you have a typo in the `Result` definition: `b?: {type: "c"}` should be `type: "b"`. [And it works](https://tsplay.dev/mplypm).

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful explanation.